# Installing TFS for VS2003

Tags: tfs, windows-7-x64, visual-studio-2003

I have `VS2003 SP1 .Net 1.1` installed on `Win7 64` bit machine.

I installed the `Visual Studio Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider (64-bit)`.

When I start VS, goto Tools > Options > Source Control, TFS is not available.

The order of install was

```
- VS2003
- VS2003 SP1
- MSSCI Provider
```

Any ideas??

UPDATE - After checking with a coworker, he performed the same steps I did.

On his PC, File > Source Control displays MS TFS, 
where as my PC displays `MS VSS` (both are obviously spelled out).

Comment: Imagine this... I installed Visual Studio Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider ( not the 64-bit flavor) and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine this... I installed Visual Studio Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider ( not the 64-bit flavor) and it works